# Assigning a different ViewSource in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm experimenting with C#/.net/WPF all for the first time.  I've created a project and set up a datasource (just a table with some sample data) and created two tableadapters named Prods and Prods1 - the latter has a filter applied in the query to return slightly different results.  I've dropped both tables on my form and both dutifully display their respective data.

I thought I would then swap the data source for each.  So the default generated Window_Loaded:

```
MSDSTest.prodtestDataSet prodtestDataSet = ((MSDSTest.prodtestDataSet)(this.FindResource("prodtestDataSet")));
// Load data into the table Prods. You can modify this code as needed.
MSDSTest.prodtestDataSetTableAdapters.ProdsTableAdapter prodtestDataSetProdsTableAdapter = new MSDSTest.prodtestDataSetTableAdapters.ProdsTableAdapter();
prodtestDataSetProdsTableAdapter.Fill(prodtestDataSet.Prods);
System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource prodsViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("prodsViewSource")));
prodsViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
// Load data into the table Prods1. You can modify this code as needed.
MSDSTest.prodtestDataSetTableAdapters.Prods1TableAdapter prodtestDataSetProds1TableAdapter = new MSDSTest.prodtestDataSetTableAdapters.Prods1TableAdapter();
prodtestDataSetProds1TableAdapter.Fill(prodtestDataSet.Prods1);
System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource prods1ViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("prods1ViewSource")));
prods1ViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
```

I now want to make the first data grid (prodsViewSource) instead display the data for the second table, and ignore the second table entirely.  So, I changed that as follows:

```
MSDSTest.prodtestDataSet prodtestDataSet = ((MSDSTest.prodtestDataSet)(this.FindResource("prodtestDataSet")));
// Load data into the table Prods. You can modify this code as needed.
MSDSTest.prodtestDataSetTableAdapters.Prods1TableAdapter prodtestDataSetProdsTableAdapter = new MSDSTest.prodtestDataSetTableAdapters.Prods1TableAdapter();
prodtestDataSetProdsTableAdapter.Fill(prodtestDataSet.Prods1);
System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource prodsViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("prodsViewSource")));
prodsViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
```

With the second block having been commented out.

I must be missing something fundamental - what I *think* I'm doing is redefining the prodtestDataSetProdsTableAddapter variable to use an instance of the prods1 table adapter, and then using that to populate the prodsViewSource grid on the form, but I end up with a blank.  Where's my error?

Answer (score 0):

...

Well, I posted this after beating my head against it for an hour and, minutes later, realized the FAR easier thing to do is to just change the datacontext property of the grid in question.

I would still like to understand why doing it the vastly more complicated-bordering-on-Rube-Goldbergian way didn't work, though, so if anyone can explain that, it would still be welcome.